# How can I specify list of agents available in a given agent pool and fetch any available agent from that list using yaml[Azure pipeline]

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to specify list of agents, for example: I have agents available from agent1 to agent10 and agent40 to agent60 from this range I would like to fetch any available agent for the pipeline execution. And all these agents are in the same pool.

Currently I am parameterizing agent value and passing it during Queue time as shown below:
[image: Queue time variable for fetching agent name]

And it is fetched in yaml file as shown below:
[image: Fetching the variable value and passing it to demand for agent name]

Comment: Hi Akhil Nair, and welcome to stack overflow. Can I make a suggestion? Your question would be better if, instead of using links to screenshots, you include all the relevant information in the question directly, in text. For example, by copying and pasting the yaml code in.
It will help readability, indexability, etc.
Remember, on this site you're encouraged to [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30745075) your question to improve it as much as possible.

Comment: @VinceBowdren: I have also submitted an edit request for this question, I hope someone approves my edit request so that the images are visible to the community.

Comment: Thanks @VinceBowdren for the suggestion, will keep this in mind next time while asking questions.

Comment: @TejasNagchandi thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, but as far as I know Azure Devops doesn't support specifying the list of agent machines.

My understanding can be supported using this note available on the documentation of [demands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

> Checking for the existence of a capability (exists) and checking for a specific string in a capability (equals) are the only two supported operations for demands.

So `exists` and `equals` are the only two possibilities, and nothing like `in`

Instead you can define a [user-defined capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#capabilities) for the agents that you need.

For example:
if you add "Test" capability to agent1 to agent10 and agent40 to agent60 of AutomationAgent pool. Then you can use following demand.

```
pool:
  name: AutomationAgent
  demands: Test
```

This would be same as below. But like I said earlier that `in` is not available yet.

```
pool:
  name: AutomationAgent
  demands:
    - Agent.Name -in (agent1, agent2, agent3.... agent10, agent40.... agent60)
```

Comment: This is correct. Azure DevOps gives you three ways of selecting an agent.

1. What pool they're in
2. What their capabilities are
3. What their agent name is.
The first two will pick from a range of agents. The third will only target the agent you named.

Comment: @sonofhamer: Thank you will try to use user-defined capabilites so that I can get any available agent I require in the pool.

Comment: Is it possible for the pipeline to determine which agent is available in the pool? Say I have an agent pool with two agents installed. If one my pipelines is using agent1 to run the build and another pipeline has been triggered, is there a way to configure it in such a way that if it sees that agent1 is being used then it will use agent2 instead, and vice-versa?